# postgresql doesn't like multiple commas

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm working with a php script that compiles data into insert statements for a postgresql database. It was originally written for a mysql database, so there are, of course, some differences.

One thing I've run into that I can't seem to figure out, is postgresql not liking this type of statement:

```
INSERT INTO table ( col1, col2, col3, col4 ) VALUES ( 'value',,'value','value' );
```

Any time there's a missing value, the query errs at the point of the double commas.

Any ideas on how to bypass this? The fields all have varying datatypes so using a '' as a filler fails if the col is expecting an int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL is following the SQL standard here. Your statement is invalid, so it produces an error.

You must either:

- Dynamically generate the column-name list to include only columns you want to set; or
- Use the keyword `DEFAULT` to say "do whatever you'd do if I hadn't specified this column"

  e.g

  ```
  INSERT INTO table ( col1, col2, col3, col4 )
  VALUES ( 'value',DEFAULT,'value','value' );
  ```

Note that the `DEFAULT` keyword is *not* quoted. It isn't an identifier or a literal. It's a keyword and must be unquoted. This means you *cannot pass it as a query parameter* via most parameterized statement query interfaces.

That means that either way, you're stuck with dynamic SQL.

I think this is a real flaw in most SQL client interfaces, which should provide a generic object you can pass to specify "make this column a default field", or a `setDefault(paramname)` method, or similar. Unfortunately, that won't help you, because most of them don't do it.

You *can* pass `NULL` as the placeholder if the column is nullable, but this is not the same thing as passing `DEFAULT`. If you use the `DEFAULT` keyword then any `DEFAULT` expression on the column is used, as if you hadn't specified the column at all. If you use `NULL`, any `DEFAULT` expression on the column definition is overridden and ignored.

Comment: I think `NULL` is going to be my option here, but I've run into another issue. How to tell if the cell is blank that I'm reading from. I've tried `if( $cell == '' or $cell == ' ')` but it's not catching the missing values.

Comment: NULL is not empty string - not on ANSI SQL databases.

Comment: The empty string '', a string with a single space ' ', and NULL are thee different things. You must test `thecolumn IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` - you cannot use `= NULL`. See an introductory database theory book or the postgresql manual for why. You should also read about joins and normalization.